# In Reactjs can I perform multiple action on a click event?

Tags: reactjs

On an "OnClick" event I am trying to perform multiple actions.

I created a custom  component with the following code:

```
const button = (props) => (
    <button onClick={props.clicked}> </button>
);
```

Here is the code that uses the  component and successfully changes "state" variables to "true", "false" and "false" respectively:

```
class TicketModal extends Component {
    state = {
        showSelection: false,
        showPayment: true,
        showConfirm: true
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Button clicked={() => {
                this.setState({showSelection: true});
                this.setState({showPayment: false});
                this.setState({showConfirm: false})
            }}>
            </Button>
        )
    }
}
```

Alternately, I can use the following code which instead of changing "state" variables, passes "click" to "props.close":

```
class TicketModal extends Component {
    state = {
        showSelection: false,
        showPayment: true,
        showConfirm: true
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Button clicked={this.props.close}></Button>
        )
    }
}
```

which is then handled by the "closeModalHandler" event handler in the following container and successfully changes the "state" variable to "false":

```
class EventsList extends Component {
    state = {
        showTicketModal: true
    };

    closeModalHandler = () => {
        this.setState({showTicketModal: false});
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Aux>   
                <TicketModal
                    close={this.closeModalHandler}>
                </TicketModal>
            </Aux>
        )
    };
}
```

How can I both change the "state" variables in the "TicketModal" container AND pass "click" to "props.close" all within the code in "TicketModal"?

I tried the following and while "click" was successfully passed to "props.close" the "state" changes to "showSelection", "showTicket", "showConfirm" were not executed:

```
            <Button clicked={() => {
                this.setState({showSelection: true});
                this.setState({showTicket: false});
                this.setState({showConfirm: false})
            }}>
            </Button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a handler method for the button click, then call `this.props.close` inside of the `setState` callback.

Something like this:

```
class TicketModal extends Component {
    state = {
        showSelection: false,
        showPayment: true,
        showConfirm: true
    }

    handleButtonClick = event => {
        this.setState({
            showSelection: true,
            showPayment: false,
            showConfirm: false
        }, () => {
            this.props.close(event);
            // or, if you don't want to pass the event
            // this.props.close();
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Button clicked={this.handleButtonClick}></Button>
        )
    }
}
```